# Android public static var in service

Tags: android, static-variables

I'm trying to use statuc variable in my app to be used to keep tracking a certain variable, my service code, I've only pasted what's necessary

```
public class TestService extends Service {

    public static HashMap<Long, Integer> testMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

        registerReceiver();
        testMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();
    }


    private final BroadcastReceiver testReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(UPDATE)) {

                long key = intent.getLongExtra("key", -1);
                int value = intent.getIntExtra("value", -1);
                //Make sure I insert it once for testing purposes 
                 if (testMap.get(key) == null)
                    testMap.put(key, value); 

                  //This one prints the value fine
                  Log.i(TAG,testMap.get(key));
                }               
            }         
    };
}
```

And then I try to access it inside my cursor adapter but I'm always getting null,

```
private static class MyCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_layout, parent, false);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View view, final Context context, Cursor cursor) {

    Integer value = TestService.testMap.get(key);
    //When I check value here, it's always null
    if (value != null)
        Log.i(TAG, value) 
    else 
        Log.i(TAG, "Key value is NULL")
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the value of `key` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not finishing your service, because everytime it calls `onCreate()` you are reinitializing your static variable. By the way, this is not a good approach, besides, static global variables are not good idea. You should communicate with your service via Intents or binding to it instead of sharing a static variable.